# Is it encouraged to flag (subjectively) inferior answers when reviewing?

Tags: discussion

So, I'm a relative noob at editing and reviewing low quality posts. I 'get' the vast majority of the reasons for recommending closure, declining suggested edits and so on

However, I came across this one this morning in a 'low-quality' queue:

[Html default hide text in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23625434/html-default-hide-text-in-mvc)

Now - there are two seemingly decent answers to this question and one seemingly not-decent answer, one of the other 'answerers' has made an accusation in a comment which may be true but can't be proven. In any case, I look at this answer and find the value of it dubious.

So - there's no option for recommending a deletion based on perceived quality (which makes sense as this is immensely subjective), so my question is - does this simply just get ignored and left against the question as an answer? Or is it encouraged that these are flagged and if so, for what reason?

This is just a curiosity for me and I generally take an "If in doubt, leave alone" cautious approach towards being destructive :)

Comment: This has now been edited by someone in an attempt to improve it, which I suppose answers my own question - it's worth down voting, but not flagging, in its original state.

Comment: I don't know about the answers but the OP has phrased his question terribly, so none of the answers are actually relevant (based on OPs further comments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can flag an answer for perceived quality issues (very low quality) - this puts it into a review queue for higher rep users to process. Also a good approach is to either down vote it or (preferably) edit it into shape.

[image]

Note that the VLQ flag is only available on zero scored answers. Once an answer has a positive score then editing and voting are your only real options.

[image]

Once an answer has a negative score it becomes a candidate for trusted users to delete.

[image]